# Why std::atomic defined as struct?

Tags: class, c++11, struct, language-lawyer

According to the clause 29.5 of Standard `std::atomic` is defined as `struct`:

```
namespace std {
template <class T> struct atomic { ...
```

I would understand if it gave direct access to data members like `std::pair`, but it doesn't. Or if it used like functor, `std::hash` for example.

What is the main reason for `std::atomic` being `struct`, not `class`?

Comment: What do you think the difference between `struct` and `class` is?  There is basically no difference; so, why do you care if it is a `struct` or a `class`?

Comment: @Yakk In general I know about difference. But want to know what guided the committee in particular.

Comment: Einie, menie, minie, moe?  It is almost as trivial a difference as "why is there a space before the `{` in one bit of example code in the standard, and none before a different `{`?"  The two terms, when defining a class, are next to interchangable as makes no difference...  I mean, I could make up a story that is plausible ("it indicates the data should be as close to POD as reasonable"), or we could maybe track down the person who did it (probably in a different library, from where it was imported to the standard), but ... why should *anybody* care?

Comment: @Yakk I just looked into `boost` and found that `boost::atomic` is defined as `class`. So version about importing is not relevant I think. Question marked with `language-lawyer` often imply that many of c++ programmers do not care about it. But I would still like to know the answer. Let it even be only a plausible story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a "language lawyer" question since there is no difference between `struct` and `class` in this context. You can feel assured that it makes absolutely no difference whether `std::atomic<T>` is a struct or a class. It is more of a "C++ history" question.

[N2145](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2145.html) says

> The proposal defines the types as POD structs and the core functions on pointers to those structs, so that types and core functions are usable from both C and C++. That is, a header included from both C and C++ can declare a variable of an atomic type and provide inline functions that operate on them. The proposal additionally provides member operators so that C++ programmers may use a more concise syntax.

Further down in the paper you can see that it seems to have been intended for implementations to be able to provide a single header that would declare member functions only in C++ mode (since structs cannot have member functions in C):

```
typedef struct atomic_bool
{
#ifdef __cplusplus
    bool lock_free() volatile;
    bool operator =( bool __v__ ) volatile;
    operator bool() volatile;
    bool swap( bool __v__ ) volatile;
    bool compare_swap( bool * __r__, bool __v__ ) volatile;
#endif
    bool __f__;
} atomic_bool;
```

I don't know whether implementations actually use such an approach. It is not necessary for them to do so. So it isn't necessary for C++ to define `std::atomic_bool` and so on as structs.

A later revision, [N2393](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2393.html), introduced the class template `std::atomic`. It doesn't explain why `std::atomic<T>` should be a struct rather than a class; I guess it was just for consistency.

Still later came a revision that actually got accepted into C++11.

As an aside, in C++23 it will finally be possible to include the C header `stdatomic.h` in C++. See [P0943](https://wg21.link/P0943).

Comment: Good catch, thanks. I've been waiting for this for 7+ years ;-D According the [tag:language-lawyer] tag: what another tag you suggest to use in such type of question? If you think that that tag isn't appropriate here.